# Capitalization of words with dashes in titles

Tags: capitalization, dashes

How would you capitalize a word in a book/article title when that word has an en dash in the middle of it? For instance, should "protein-protein interaction" be capitalized as "Protein-protein Interaction" or "Protein-Protein Interaction"?

Comment: I think this is a style issue that does not have a single, definite rule; when I worked for a company that put together large catalogs, we were required to only capitalize the first word and never the second word.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, do you mean you capitalized the first hyphenated word but not the second *and* capitalized the remaining significant words (as in the poster's example), or do you mean you had something like "Particle-particle interactions"?  That's a valid style too; I was taking the capital "I" as a constraint of the question.  @Tamás, if I'm reading you wrong, please let us know.

Comment: @Monica Cellio: I take it for granted that I have to capitalize every "significant" word in the title according to the usual capitalization rules, so yes, consider the capital I in "Interactions" as a constraint :)

Comment: I would capitalize both instances of "protein" because the en-dash is functioning as the word "to," i.e., "Protein-to-Protein." I suspect that this was actually an overgeneralization of the rule for capitalizing with hyphenated prefixes.

Comment: @Monica Cellio: I'm saying that, if the company were selling a product with that name, the policy would be to only write it as "Protein-protein Interaction".  I'm not advocating for everyone to do it that way, only that this was the policy for a major US company.

Comment: @Kosmonaut, I didn't realize that was the product name; that generally trumps style. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Capitalize each word that is a word on its own, as in "Protein–Protein Interaction". If the hyphen adds a prefix that doesn't stand on its own, like "Non-protein Elements", then capitalize the prefix. But I've seen it both ways.