# Which one is more correct, "White-eye Man" or “White-Eye Man”？

Tags: capitalization, open-vs-closed-vs-hyphenated, book-title

My son loves a kind of bird called [white-eyes,](https://www.google.com/search?q=white-eye%20bird) very much. He wants to call a character in his storybook 'white-eye man,' similar to 'spider man' or iron man. He also wants to use the name as his book's title.

I am not quite sure which one is correct between "White-eye Man" and “White-Eye Man.” Which one should he use, and does it make a difference depending on whether it is placed in the title or based on the context?

Comment: There is an argument that only the first letter of each word is subject to capitalisation and that “eye” isn’t a separate word in this context. But I think I’ve seen both forms. One can argue for a bit of artistic license as well, with -Eye capitalised so it doesn’t look left out. But this isn’t an authoritative answer, so I’ll leave it as a comment here.

Comment: This is about titles not character names: [Do you capitalize both parts of a hyphenated word in a title?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title) Conclusion is, it's a matter of style.

Comment: Yes this is a style choice, not grammar

Comment: Generally: White-eye Man.  By the way, a terrible name for a character, imo.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! As this is a given title of a person or being, the dash should be treated like a space, and all first letters should be capitalized: i.e. White-Eye Man.

I found another thread related to this:
[Capitalization of words with dashes in titles](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26964/capitalization-of-words-with-dashes-in-titles)

Comment: The other question is about *dashes,* not hyphens. Could you give a reference for your assertion about treating hyphens as spaces?

Comment: I think Stuart F and Wiser2k1 have been misled about titles and character names. In cases like this, anyway, the usage in a title would always follow the usage in the character name… and I echo Andrew Leach's request for clarification…

Comment: 'dash' and 'hyphen' are interchangeable, just speak with some EN speakers from around the world

Answer (score -1):

Spider-Man comes with a hyphen.  So, I think, it should be White-eye-Man, to avoid confusion.  There's also the point symmetry of the W and M.

Or, White-Eye Man, on the model of Iron Man, without a hyphen before the word, man, and, on the model of Spider-Man, with the capitalization of such words about a hyphen.

Answer (score -2):

White-eye is the name of a species and has a hyphen. Like all other species (lion, penguin, shark) it is not capitalised. It is spelled with a hyphen. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-eye)

White-eye man, is simply a noun1 + noun2 construction with white-eye acting attributively.

However, White-Eye Man is a name, and names are capitalised.

Comment: I think with the dash, I would forgo capitalizing eye.

Comment: @Lambie - But you capitalized "I"?